# Are there any tablets that support ubuntu?

Tags: android, tablet

I have been using ubuntu on desktops and laptops for years and I am looking at buying my first tablet. I would love to use ubuntu on it and I'm wondering if there are any tablets that I could install ubuntu on from a usb without any dramas. Or is this still a work on progress?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any devices that come with ubuntu pre installed.

As of now, there two option to run ubuntu.

1. Install desktop ubuntu and use with VNC
2. Install ubuntu touch.

**Install desktop ubuntu and use with VNC**

This is quite steps need to be done to running this. At end it is not very usable.

**Install ubuntu touch**

Ubuntu touch is operating system developed for small touch devices. read more here http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/

Both method wants devices with open (unlocked) bootloader.
For this, I suggest google nexus devices. As those are open and ubuntu touch images are ready to flashed.

Here is more details : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices